# Proper way to avoid loading a menu on each postback?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, menu

I have the following problem:
There is a big fat menu in the web application I am working on (webforms), with lots of entries. It is located in a MasterPage.
It takes quite a lot of time to load server-side (depending on the rights of the users on various items), and represents about 250kB of data for the average user.

Right now this process is repeated on each postback. I want to minimize the load on the server AND avoid all that data transfer (even if the viewstate is compressed, which helps a bit).

Because the menu is 99,9% of the time exactly the same for a given user (It only changes if the admin gives another permission), i thought about creating the HTML for the menu on sessionStart once and for all, storing the generated html clientside (in sessionStorage for instance) and re-spitting it from there.

But then I have a serious problem : all the links I've got there use a "javascript:__doPostBack()" call as href, and my pages won't allow any of that (afterall the pages aren't the source of these controls), and I won't disable pageEventValidation.

So maybe there is something wrong alltogether with the architecture of that menu…

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Why do you make all the links in the menu do a postback instead of creating just a link?

Comment: @VDWWD : It is a web application more than a website.
We need the postback behaviour for these links for several reasons.
_For instance the server keeps track of the navigation of the user
_We have some checks to do server-side before we let the user leave the page : maybe he has work in progress ? If so, we propose the save before, etc…
_Some of the links in the menu are not page redirections but actions to be done server-side : restart this or that engine, publish this, etc… In end-effect the user stays on the page.

Comment: It not at all clear how the menu bar was created? Even 10+ year old webform templates by default used bootstrap menu bars. I would think that some if not most of that menu bar will and can be cached by the browser.  250k does seem a bit large for the menu bar, but my guess would be perhaps a lot of icons????  Is the menu bar some boot strap menu, or what type of elements is the menu bar based on ? Perhaps you just load the sub-menus on demand then? There must be some detail missing here, since that menu bar size sees a bit large.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal
All that is of no real importance in fact. I can give you some info though: the menu is not your typical website menu: there are very few icons, but quite a lot of events and other metadata as attributes (there is for instance a big crypted chain that we use to check the provenance of the request in some cases).
Whereas I see that it is not a dream scenario, there is nothing I can do about that, hence my wish to avoid transfering it on each PostBack

Comment: The problem is let's say you load the menu bar with ajax after the page loads. Even if using a web end points, the menu bar will have been pulled to the client side. So, now any post-back going to post-back that whole page, and wind up posting back the menu bar. Might save some payload in that menu bar has no viewstate, but you still posting it back for any button click. Perhaps you can have sub-menus load on demand, but unless  you remove stuff from the menu bar, it going to be posted back no matter what.  All and any content or text on page will post-back on any button click.

Comment: This suggest then that buttons in the menu can can become ajax + web method calls that will/can eliminate the post back in the first place. However, any post-back that occurs is going to send the whole page to the server - along with that menu bar. So, either you reduce the size of the menu bar, or your menu buttons call web methods and don't do a post-back. I really don't see much else of a choice here. You can't have a post-back occur without the page being sent to the server, and only exception to that rule is using a update panel, but that means code behind can't change all page content.

Comment: Now, having stated all of the above? You COULD move the menu bar to a custom user control. You can then tell the server to NOT RE-RENDER the menu bar each time. (it will still be posted back, and still ride along for the round trip, but your server code will not have to run each time to re-create the menu bar. How this works is expalined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/moving-to-aspnet-20/caching

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, I managed to do what i wanted.

The rights for my menu (depending on the user) are computed at login, and stored in Session server-side (that's a lot of info, believe me)
My menus is created client-side, based on those informations.

To avoid transfering that data on each postback, I store the rights for the menu on client-side, as sessionStorage.

I can manage the postbacks manually (the links launch a __doPostBack, and I analyse the request by hand)

This way the rights are computed only once (at login time), and the html is created client-side. No data transfer.
For the rare cases where the rights have changed, they are reloaded and refreshed in sessionStorage.

Answer (score -1):

To optimize the menu in your WebForms application while maintaining event validation and postbacks, you may follow these steps:

1. Generate structured menu data on the server, including menu items and their associated event targets.
2. Load this menu data on the client side using AJAX when the page loads.
3. Dynamically render the menu on the client side by creating anchor elements (`<a>`) for each menu item and attaching click event handlers to them.
4. In the click event handlers, use JavaScript to handle menu item clicks based on their associated targets.
5. For postbacks, simulate them using the `__doPostBack` function with the appropriate arguments to maintain event validation.

```
function handleMenuItemClick(target) {
    // Simulate a postback
    __doPostBack(target, ''); // Target is the client ID of the control
}
```

This approach allows for client-side rendering of the menu, efficient handling of menu item clicks, and preservation of event validation and postback functionality. You may choose to cache the data on the client side.

Comment: Not at all convinced this will help anymore then allowing the browser to cache the menu. If you use ajax to load the menu bar, then each button click on that page (with a post-back) will require that menu bar to be re-loaded each time (no cache of the menu will occur if you pull data using ajax).  Having the server dish out a menu bar, or making a ajax call to get and grab a menu bar of the same size? You gain zero here.....

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal we need to check the local cache on the client side before making an ajax call. Ultimately the data from ajax should be cached on the client side may be using local storage. I'm not sure which point if the solution didnt make sense here.

Comment: Which end of this issue is the problem (too large of a post-back), or too large of a page load in the first place. (the poster does hint/suggest that the post-back is slow).  I'm open to if pulling the menu via ajax is better then just including the menu as part of the page load now. 100% agree that paring down, removing stuff from menu is great idea - but once that's done, then the menu is smaller, and loading via ajax, or loading as part of the page should not make much if any difference here. So 100% yes to making menu smaller. Not so much on ajax. On demand loading could help if practical

Comment: As a FYI? It was NOT me who downvoted your suggestion. I open to your idea, but regardless of me having some questions about loading the menu with ajax (as opposed to including in page), I most certainly did not downvote your suggesting here.

Comment: Thanks for your input.
@AlbertD.Kallal My main concern here is just efficiency. While the page load time is most of the time absolutely acceptable (the server takes about 200ms to generate the menu, and transfering 250kB is not thaaaat long), I still find it completely stupid to do it at each and every postback, especially beacause 99,99% of the time the exact same menu is loaded again and again.
BTW I didn't downvote either…